# Camera 'Failed to start" after button pressed on the left side

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I started the camera on the Galaxy Tab 3 10.1. One of the buttons on the left side was pressed by a customer.

Now whenever I try starting the Camera I get a "Camera Failed to Start" message. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the tablet? That message usually means some application (probably the camera app itself) has a 'grip' on the camera hardware. Usually the first port of call is a reboot. Then if you have to try clearing the cache/data of the camera app.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Camera" in "All apps" of the settings menu and selecting "Clear Data" should do the trick.